# Rotating sprites relative to it's container has bug while moving

Tags: c++, geometry, sfml

I've been working on making my game engine, and I've been having A LOT of trouble dealing with rotating a sprite relative to a container. (it's used to overlay multiple sprites and be able to easily change their location relative to the center of the object. I need to be able to rotate the object and keep their relative location proper).

I've got it pretty much working. I can rotate the sprite, and all the sprites relative locations stay the same. I can even do this while moving the sprite (it will move AND rotate at the same time). Unless the sprite starts moving again while the sprite is turning. When this happens, the sprite continues to keep it's orientation relative to the container, but will jump back to it's original X/Y location relative to the container.

I stripped down my code to provide a stand alone example program, and the bug persists. To test it, you'll need SFML 2.1, and the following source code

main.cpp

```
#include<SFML\Graphics.hpp>

#include<vector>

#include"sprite_holder.h"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 640), "Things don't work so gewd :<");
    std::vector<sprite_holder> sprite_holders;

    sprite_holders.push_back(sprite_holder(50,50));
    sprite_holders.push_back(sprite_holder(150,100));
    sprite_holders.push_back(sprite_holder(250,50));
    sprite_holders.push_back(sprite_holder(350,50));
    sprite_holders.push_back(sprite_holder(450,100));
    sprite_holders.push_back(sprite_holder(550,50));

    float move1 = -100;
    float move2 = -100;
    float move3 = -100;
    float move4 = -100;
    sf::Clock timer;

    sprite_holders[3].adjust_child_pos(1,0,20,0);
    sprite_holders[4].adjust_child_pos(-1,0,20,0);
    sprite_holders[5].adjust_child_pos(-1,0,20,0);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color(255,0,255));



        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sprite_holders.size(); i++) {

            sprite_holders[i].update(timer.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds());

            for(unsigned int j = 0; j < sprite_holders[i].sprites.size(); j++) {

                window.draw(sprite_holders[i].sprites[j].first);
            }
        }


        // This block of code will make the left-most sprite_holder move up and down constantly
        if(sprite_holders[0].transform_complete(POSITION)) {
                move1 *= -1;
                sprite_holders[0].adjust_pos(0,move1,1200);
        }

        // This block of code will make the sprite_holder second from the left spin constantly
        if(sprite_holders[1].transform_complete(ANGLE)) sprite_holders[1].adjust_angle(360,800);

        // This block of code will make the sprite_holder third from the left move up and down AND spin constantly
        if(sprite_holders[2].transform_complete(ANGLE)) sprite_holders[2].adjust_angle(360,800);
        if(sprite_holders[2].transform_complete(POSITION)) {
                move2 *= -1;
                sprite_holders[2].adjust_pos(0,move2,1200);
        }

        // This block of code will make the sprite_holder third from the right move up and down constantly
        if(sprite_holders[3].transform_complete(POSITION)) {
                move3 *= -1;
                sprite_holders[3].adjust_pos(0,move3,1200);
        }

        // This block of code will make the sprite_holder second from the right spin constantly
        if(sprite_holders[4].transform_complete(ANGLE)) sprite_holders[4].adjust_angle(360,800);

        // This block of code will make the right-most sprite_holder move up and down AND spin constantly
        if(sprite_holders[5].transform_complete(ANGLE)) sprite_holders[5].adjust_angle(360,800);
        if(sprite_holders[5].transform_complete(POSITION)) {
                move4 *= -1;
                sprite_holders[5].adjust_pos(0,move4,1200);
        }

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

sprite_holder.cpp

```
#include "sprite_holder.h"

sprite_holder::sprite_holder(float x, float y)
{
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;

    cAngle = 0;

    lastUpdateTime = -1;

    // These are here so I could remove some functions to make tracking the error down much simpler.
    // Ignore everything from here till the end of the constructor. It's just loading the sprites and texures
    // into memory, initializing the offsets to 0, and setting the initial positions

    sf::Sprite sprite1;
    sf::Texture texture1;

    texture1.loadFromFile("heart_back.png");
    textures.push_back(texture1);

    sprite1.setTexture(textures.back());
    sprite1.setPosition(xPos,yPos);
    sf::Vector2u spriteSize = textures.back().getSize();
    sprite1.setOrigin(spriteSize.x/2, spriteSize.y/2);

    offset offset1;

    offset1.xOffset = 0;
    offset1.yOffset = 0;

    offset1.angleOffset = 0;
    offset1.tiltOffset = 0;

    sf::Sprite sprite2;
    sf::Texture texture2;

    texture2.loadFromFile("heart.png");
    textures.push_back(texture2);

    sprite2.setTexture(textures.back());
    sprite2.setPosition(xPos,yPos);
    spriteSize = textures.back().getSize();
    sprite2.setOrigin(spriteSize.x/2, spriteSize.y/2);

    offset offset2;

    offset2.xOffset = 0;
    offset2.yOffset = 0;

    offset2.angleOffset = 0;
    offset2.tiltOffset = 0;

    sprites.push_back(std::make_pair(sprite1,offset1));
    sprites.push_back(std::make_pair(sprite2,offset2));
}

// This is called every frame the window is redrawn.
// (note, the reason I calculate everything based on the timeElapsed since last draw is because
// I don't want the application's speed to be bound to it's framerate)
void sprite_holder::update(int timeElapsed)
{

    // Because SFML hates textures for some reason, I'd normally have classes containing the sf::Texture, and keep pointer instances of
    // said classes. But since that'd complicate the code a little, I'm just re-loading the image every time I need to draw it. That
    // keeps the sprites from being white boxes.
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++) sprites[i].first.setTexture(textures[i]);


    int transformToRemove = -1;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<transforms.size(); i++) {
        if(transforms[i].first.startTime == -1) transforms[i].first.startTime = timeElapsed; // This makes anything transforms created before the first update use the proper start time

        float percentComplete = (float)(timeElapsed - transforms[i].first.startTime) / transforms[i].first.duration; // this calculates what percentage of the transform's time duration has passed

        if(transforms[i].first.type == POSITION) {
            if( calculate_transform_pos(percentComplete,i) == true ) transformToRemove = i; // This will calculate the x and y value for the current completion percentage of the transform and remove it if it's 100% complete
            render_children_pos(); // This sets all the sf::Sprites to their proper location reletive to the sprite_holder
        } else {
            // This will calculate the angle value for the current completion percentage of the transform and remove it if it's 100% complete
            if( calculate_transform_angle(percentComplete,i) == true ) transformToRemove = i;
            render_children_angle(); // This sets all the sf::Sprites to their proper location reletive to the sprite_holder
        }
    }

    lastUpdateTime = timeElapsed;

    if(transformToRemove != -1) transforms.erase(transforms.begin()+transformToRemove);


}

// This is a function that will let you know if a given transformation has finished.
// It's used so you can do something as soon as a transformation is complete.
// (an example would be to make a sprite rotate forever by telling it to spin by 360 degrees,
// whenever it's finished spinning by 360 degrees)
bool sprite_holder::transform_complete(transform_type type, int spriteIndex)
{
    if(lookup_transform(type,spriteIndex) == -1) return true;

    return false;
}

// This will move the sprite_holder's center point by
// the x and y values provided. The argument "duration"
// provides a time in miliseconds the movement will take.
// (note, children will keep their reletive position to the sprite_holder)
void sprite_holder::adjust_pos(float x, float y, int duration)
{
    int transformIndex = lookup_transform(POSITION);

    if(transformIndex == -1) {
        transformIndex = transforms.size();

        transform newTransform;
        newTransform.type = POSITION;

        transforms.push_back(std::make_pair(newTransform,-1));
    }

    transforms[transformIndex].first.startingA = xPos;
    transforms[transformIndex].first.startingB = yPos;

    transforms[transformIndex].first.targetA   = x + xPos;
    transforms[transformIndex].first.targetB   = y + yPos;

    transforms[transformIndex].first.duration  = duration;
    transforms[transformIndex].first.startTime = lastUpdateTime;
}


// This will rotate the sprite_holder by the angle
// value provided. The argument "duration" provides
// a time in miliseconds the rotation will take.
// (note, children will keep their reletive position and angle to the sprite_holder)
void sprite_holder::adjust_angle(float angle, int duration)
{
    int transformIndex = lookup_transform(ANGLE);

    if(transformIndex == -1) {
        transformIndex = transforms.size();

        transform newTransform;
        newTransform.type = ANGLE;

        transforms.push_back(std::make_pair(newTransform,-1));
    }

    transforms[transformIndex].first.startingA = cAngle;

    transforms[transformIndex].first.targetA   = angle + cAngle;

    transforms[transformIndex].first.duration  = duration;
    transforms[transformIndex].first.startTime = lastUpdateTime;
}

// This will move the sf::Sprite specified by spriteIndex
// by the x and y values provided. This movement will last
// as long as the provided duration argument.
void sprite_holder::adjust_child_pos(int spriteIndex, float x, float y, int duration)
{
    if (spriteIndex == -1) spriteIndex = sprites.size()-1;
    int transformIndex = lookup_transform(ANGLE,spriteIndex);

    if(transformIndex == -1) {
        transformIndex = transforms.size();

        transform newTransform;
        newTransform.type = POSITION;

        transforms.push_back(std::make_pair(newTransform,spriteIndex));
    }

    transforms[transformIndex].first.startingA = sprites[spriteIndex].second.xOffset;
    transforms[transformIndex].first.startingB = sprites[spriteIndex].second.yOffset;

    transforms[transformIndex].first.targetA   = x + sprites[spriteIndex].second.xOffset;
    transforms[transformIndex].first.targetB   = y + sprites[spriteIndex].second.yOffset;

    transforms[transformIndex].first.duration  = duration;
    transforms[transformIndex].first.startTime = lastUpdateTime;
}


// This will rotate the sf::Sprite specified by spriteIndex
// by the angle value provided. This movement will last
// as long as the provided duration argument.
void sprite_holder::adjust_child_angle(int spriteIndex, float angle, int duration)
{
    if (spriteIndex == -1) spriteIndex = sprites.size()-1;

    int transformIndex = lookup_transform(ANGLE,spriteIndex);

    if(transformIndex == -1) {
        transformIndex = transforms.size();

        transform newTransform;
        newTransform.type = ANGLE;

        transforms.push_back(std::make_pair(newTransform,spriteIndex));
    }

    transforms[transformIndex].first.startingA = sprites[spriteIndex].second.tiltOffset;

    transforms[transformIndex].first.targetA   = angle + sprites[spriteIndex].second.tiltOffset;

    transforms[transformIndex].first.duration  = duration;
    transforms[transformIndex].first.startTime = lastUpdateTime;
}

// This function is called every time a transform updates either an sf::Sprite or the sprite_holder's position
// note: the reason angleOffset is set here is because the reletive angle to the sprite_holder only changes when it's
// reletive position does. It doesn't matter how much you rotate the sprite_holder, the reletive angle of the sf::Sprite is the same
void sprite_holder::render_children_pos()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++) {
        sprites[i].first.setPosition(xPos+sprites[i].second.xOffset, yPos+sprites[i].second.yOffset);

        sf::Vector2f spritePos = sprites[i].first.getPosition();

        sprites[i].second.angleOffset = atan2(spritePos.y - yPos, spritePos.x - xPos);
    }

}

void sprite_holder::render_children_angle()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sprites.size(); i++) {
        sf::Vector2f spritePos = sprites[i].first.getPosition();

        float radius = sqrt(pow((xPos - spritePos.x), 2) + pow((yPos - spritePos.y), 2)); // xPos and yPos are the container's x and y position

        float angle = sprites[i].second.angleOffset + (cAngle /180*3.14); // cAngle is the container's angle

        float newX = xPos + radius * cos(angle);
        float newY = yPos + radius * sin(angle);

        sprites[i].first.setPosition(newX, newY); // this sets the sprite's x and y coordinates
        sprites[i].first.setRotation(cAngle + sprites[i].second.tiltOffset); // this sets the spries rotation around it's local axis. it only affects the sprite's orientation, not position
    }
}

// This function returns the index of the transform.
// If you give it a spriteIndex value, it'll look for transforms
// bound to an sf::Sprite contained within the sprite_holder.
// Otherwise, it'll look for transforms bound to the sprite_holder.
int sprite_holder::lookup_transform(transform_type type, int spriteIndex)
{
    int result = -1;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < transforms.size(); i++) {
        if(transforms[i].first.type == type) {
            if(transforms[i].second == spriteIndex) result = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;

}

    // This returns the value a given percent between the start and end value
    // It's so I can calculate what is 33.2687% between 36.2 and 55, or some other such
    // nonesense that occurs when moving things around
float sprite_holder::percentage_along_distance(float startValue,float endValue, float percentComplete)
{
    return ((1-percentComplete) *  startValue) + (percentComplete * endValue);
}

// This function will set either an sf::Sprite or a sprite_holder (the transform provided by transformIndex tells it which to set)
// to the proper location a given percentage through the transformation.
// For example, if the start point of the transform is 0,0, the end point is 0,10, and we tell it we're 50% done with the transform
// it'll set the proper entity to 0,5
bool sprite_holder::calculate_transform_pos(float percentComplete, int transformIndex) // returns true when the transform is finished
{
    float x;
    float y;

    if(percentComplete < 1) {
        x = percentage_along_distance(transforms[transformIndex].first.startingA, transforms[transformIndex].first.targetA, percentComplete);
        y = percentage_along_distance(transforms[transformIndex].first.startingB, transforms[transformIndex].first.targetB, percentComplete);
    } else {
        x = transforms[transformIndex].first.targetA;
        y = transforms[transformIndex].first.targetB;
    }

    if(transforms[transformIndex].second == -1) {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
    } else {
        int spriteIndex = transforms[transformIndex].second;

        sprites[spriteIndex].second.xOffset = x;
        sprites[spriteIndex].second.yOffset = y;
    }

    if(percentComplete >= 1) return true;
    return false;
}


// This does the same as calculate_transform_pos, but with angles. I'm planning on merging the two functions, but haven't yet come up with a good way to go about it.
bool sprite_holder::calculate_transform_angle(float percentComplete, int transformIndex) // returns true when the transform is finished
{
    float angle;

    if(percentComplete < 1) {
        angle = percentage_along_distance(transforms[transformIndex].first.startingA, transforms[transformIndex].first.targetA, percentComplete);
    } else {
        angle = transforms[transformIndex].first.targetA;
    }

    if(transforms[transformIndex].second == -1) {
        cAngle = angle;
    } else {
        int spriteIndex = transforms[transformIndex].second;

        sprites[spriteIndex].second.tiltOffset = angle;
    }

    if(percentComplete >= 1) return true;
    return false;
}
```

offset.h

```
#ifndef _LBMOON_OFFSET_H
#define _LBMOON_OFFSET_H

struct offset
{
    float xOffset;
    float yOffset;

    float angleOffset;
    float tiltOffset;
};


#endif
```

sprite_holder.h

```
#ifndef _LBMOON_SPRITE_H
#define _LBMOON_SPRITE_H

#include<SFML\Graphics.hpp>

#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<utility>

#include <math.h>

#include "transform.h"
#include "offset.h"

class sprite_holder
{
public:
    // General Interface Functions
    sprite_holder(float x, float y);

    void update(int timeElapsed);

    bool transform_complete(transform_type type, int spriteIndex=-1);

    // Shell functions (transform the whole sprite)
    void adjust_pos(float x, float y, int duration);
    void adjust_angle(float angle, int duration);


    // Child functions (transform a specific drawable)
    // note: when passing drawIndex, -1 means the top drawable
    void adjust_child_pos(int spriteIndex, float x, float y, int duration);
    void adjust_child_angle(int spriteIndex, float angle, int duration);

    std::vector<std::pair<sf::Sprite,offset>> sprites;
    std::vector<sf::Texture> textures;

protected:
    int lookup_transform(transform_type type, int spriteIndex = -1);

    void render_children_pos();
    void render_children_angle();

    float percentage_along_distance(float startValue,float endValue, float percentComplete);

    float xPos;
    float yPos;

    float cAngle;

    int lastUpdateTime;

    std::vector<std::pair<transform,int>> transforms;

private:
    bool calculate_transform_pos  (float percentComplete, int transformIndex); // returns true when the transform is finished
    bool calculate_transform_angle(float percentComplete, int transformIndex); // returns true when the transform is finished

};

#endif
```

transform.h

```
#ifndef _LBMOON_TRANSFORM_H
#define _LBMOON_TRANSFORM_H

enum transform_type{UNKNOWN=-1,POSITION=0,SCALE,ANGLE};

struct transform
{
    transform_type type;

    int startTime;
    int duration;

    float startingA;
    float startingB;

    float targetA;
    float targetB;
};

#endif
```

You'll also want to put the following images with the program:

http://legacyblade.com/images/heart.png

http://legacyblade.com/images/heart_back.png

I've been working on getting this class working for a couple weeks now, and after testing all day to find the source of this particularly baffling error, I've come up dry. So thanks for reading this! Any help you could provide would be amazing.

Comment: That's a lot of code, could you reduce it to the strict minimum to illustrate your problem ?

Comment: That is the strict minimum x.x All the parts work perfectly on their own. It's just the interaction between these particular parts that causes the problem.